# Flutter, como compilar o projeto para rodar nativo no android

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

Estou iniciando no Flutter, gostaria de saber como faço para compilar o meu projeto para ser um aplicativo nativo, como por exemplo para Android. Como posso fazer isso pela linha de comando? Achei o andoid studio muito confuso.

Obrigado pela ajuda pessoal!

Comment: Algumas pessoas usam o vs code com o plugin do dart e do flutter no lugar do android studio.

Comment: Pra ele rodar no android se não me engano ou é ´flutter run´ ou ´flutter run android´

Comment: @JulianaMarques `flutter run` roda em modo debug. Minha resposta esclarece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O SDK Flutter por si só tem seus build modes, no qual poderíamos fazer algo diferente dependendo o modo em que nosso app está rodando, são eles:

- **Debug:** É o único modo que podemos rodar em emuladores, conhecido pelo banner debug apresentado ao rodar o app. As [assertions](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert) no código são habilitadas, assim como o [observatory](https://dart-lang.github.io/observatory/). Possui um maior tamanho de pacote final gerado, uma vez que é otimizado apenas para o desenvolvimento. Para rodar basta o comando `flutter run`.
- **Profile:** Ainda mantém algumas funcionalidades de debug, só pode ser executado em devices físicos, para manter a performance real. Para rodar basta `flutter run --profile`.
- **Release:** Também roda apenas em devices físicos, é o modo em que usamos para gerar o pacote final para as lojas, pois é otimizado para execução e tamanho final dos binários, gerado através do `flutter run --release` ou `flutter build`.

Então, para compilar uma versão final, que gere o APK compilando AOT no seu device, basta `flutter run --release` ou `flutter build`.

Fonte em [português](https://medium.com/flutter-comunidade-br/flutter-ready-to-go-pt-br-16d1e5255fcf) e [inglês](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-ready-to-go-e59873f9d7de).

Answer (score 1):

Basta executar na linha de comando `flutter run --release`

Quanto ao Android Studio, uma boa alternativa que o pessoal já tem adotado a bastante tempo é usar o Visual Studio Code, da Microsoft. É simples de usar, leve e personalizável com grande repositório de extensões disponíveis.